# How would you calculate the sedimentation rate of a coarse chemical suspension under gravity using a centrifuge?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, chemistry

If the sedimentation rate can be determined for a coarse chemical suspension or a suspension containing large particles (i.e., particles with radii between 100 to 200μm) in a medium like vegetable oil, Can they also be determined if a centrifuge was used to speed up the separation process, if so would it be equivalent to what is obtained under the force of gravity itself? Any help with this question would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is possible if the inertia force from spinning is greater than the drag force on the particle due to viscosity. Note that inertia is a different matter from gravity.

Comment: https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/technical-documents/technical-article/protein-biology/protein-pulldown/centrifugation-basics

Comment: through the use of nondimensional similitude parameters.